# matplotlib plt.yticks precisely on y values (multiple lines)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have this plot:

[image]

I would like to show the exact prices where the markers "o" are.

Current code is:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(18,10))
plt.plot(visas_df["years"],visas_df["published_finals"],color='green',marker="o");
plt.plot(visas_df["years"],visas_df["expired_finals"],color='red',marker="o");
plt.plot(visas_df["years"],visas_df["visas"],color='blue',marker="o");
plt.xticks(visas_df.years)
plt.title("Visas Per Year",fontsize=20)
plt.xlabel("Year",fontsize=18)
plt.ylabel("Visas (Final & Provisional)",fontsize=18)
plt.legend(["Newly Published","Expired","Total Visas"],fontsize = 20)
plt.grid(visible=True,color='black')
plt.minorticks_on()
plt.grid(visible=True,which="minor")
```

When I try to use:

```
plt.yticks(visas_df.published_finals)
plt.yticks(visas_df.expired_finals)
plt.yticks(visas_df.visas)
```

The plot becomes jumbled:

[image]

I would like to grab the values from the df column and display them or display them on the "o" marker. Either way is fine.

Any thoughts on that? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

After some aeons of fidgeting with matplotlib, I managed to put the values on the markers.
This was done by using matplotlib. axes.Axes. text

Changes to the code below:

```
fig,ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(25,15))
```

The following code uses ax.text and is duplicated 3 times since I have 3 lines.

```
for i in range(len(visas_df.years)):
ax.text(visas_df.years[i],visas_df.published_finals[i],visas_df.published_finals[i]/1000,
size=12,verticalalignment ='top',horizontalalignment ='right',
color="g",fontweight="bold",fontstretch="condensed"),

ax.text(visas_df.years[i],visas_df.expired_finals[i],visas_df.expired_finals[i]/1000,
size=12,verticalalignment ='bottom',horizontalalignment ='right',
color="r",fontweight="bold",fontstretch="condensed"),

ax.text(visas_df.years[i],visas_df.visas[i],visas_df.visas[i]/1000,
size=12,verticalalignment ='bottom',horizontalalignment ='right',
color="b",fontweight="bold",fontstretch="condensed")

ax.set(xlim =(2000,2023), ylim =(-25000, 175000))
```

The rest of the code is pretty much the same and here's the outcome:
[image]